# Restore SQL Server database from .sql files

Tags: backup, sql-server-2012, schema, ssms

So we had an encrypted database that puked and killed our whole SQL Server setup. Sucks about our data, but we were smart enough to have our data structures / stored procedures / functions in Git

The problem is they're saved as `.sql` files.

Is there anyway we can batch restore our schema from directories full of these files?

I've looked around and I can only find tutorials for restoring from `.bak` files or `.mdf`'s. This isn't the lazy man's way out- I just need to find a solution ASAP. Any advice or resources/ anything at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks Interwebs,

Dylan

Comment: You can surely execute a SQL script file from sqlcmd, but the real question is how did you script this out? Sequence does matter here (think foreign key relationships), as well as if the scripts contain all DDL. If you did the "Generate scripts..." from SSMS you should be fine. But the true backup and restore should have been more traditional with native full/diff/tran log backups.

Comment: We did do the generate. If nothing else this has been a learning experience. Working on solution now. Will post when done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you just need to execute the collection of schema scripts to recreate your database? You could execute them one by one or create a batch file and use [SQLCMD to execute all script files in directory](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/c0a31e25-d41f-4404-809b-b1188b7e1be6/)

```
for /r "%ScriptPath%" %%X in (*.sql) do ( 
   sqlcmd -S%ServerName% -d%DBName% -b -i "%%X"
)
```

Comment: I'm sure I could have written a bat fie, but I got it done pretty quickly in python:
http://tinyurl.com/a5q32uf

Answer (score 0):

Considering the large size of the data structure I was trying restore, running each files individually was not a practical solution. I'm sure I could have written a bat fie, but I got it done pretty quickly in python:

```
import os, subprocess
processDir = 'C:\\Database-master\\'
files = os.listdir(processDir)
for f in files:
    db = processDir + f
    #potentially drop corrupt db and create new ones with f
    scripts = os.listdir(db)
    for script in scripts:
        path = db + '\\' + script
        proc = subprocess.Popen('sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1 -i "' + path +'"', shell=True)
        proc.wait()
```